# Vista se carga antes que los datos en el controlador

Tags: ionic

soy nuevo en Ionic, y estoy haciendo una app que desde un botón, llama a una function en un controlador. La function hace http y trae datos con php para hacer un list en otra vista. Pero......la vista se carga y los datos aún no están disponibles. (El PHP funciona correcto) Además, tengo variable lógica, que indica cuando la vista se carga que aún los datos no están. Les agradeceré si me ayudan para solucionar este...asincronismo? Muchas gracias !

```
 var request = $http({
        method: "post",
            url: "http://............php",
            data: {
                ciudad: $scope.ciuid,
            },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        });
        /* Successful HTTP post request or not */
        request.success(function (data) {

        $scope.arrs = [];
        for (var prop in data) {
            $scope.arrs.push(data[prop]);
        }    
        $scope.AtraccLoaded = true;
        alert($scope.arrs[0].aarqu); // muestra dato, correcto !
```

Vista ----------------------------------

```
<a ng-repeat="arr in arrs" ng-if="AtraccLoaded" 
               href="#/{{arr.anomb}}"
               class="item item-thumbnail-left">
              <img ng-src="{{ arr.imag }}">
              <h2>{{ arr.anomb }}</h2>
              <h4>{{ arr.adire }}</h4>
    </a>
```

Comment: Que versión de ionic utilizas?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Que se cargue la vista antes que los datos no es problema en angularjs (y menos usando ionic), ya que una de las características más destacables de esta librería es el 2-Way-data-binding, que hace que esté comprobando todo el rato el modelo con la vista.

Ya que estás usando ionic prueba a usar las etiquetas de ionic list:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
    Hello, {{item}}!
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/

Además no creo que debas usar el href en tu etiqueta.

Answer (score 0):

Es por que estás realizando una llamada asíncrona. Recuerda que al usar $http implica esperar al servidor por una respuesta y esto lleva tiempo hasta que obtengas una respuesta, por lo tanto debes manejarlo con una promesa($q angularjs promise).

Importante: No mezcles tu modelo MVC en el controlador solo debe haber consumo de puntos de api. Y tus definiciones deben estar separadas.

Ejemplo consumo de api:

```
angular.module('ciudades', []).service('Ciudades', ['$q','$http', function($q, $http) {
    var self = {

        listaCiudades: function(_ciudad) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();//esta es la promesa que luego se va a resolver

            var url = "http://.....php";
            var data = {ciudad: _ciudad};

            $http.post(url, data).then(function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);//response son los datos que retorna tu php

            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);//si algo va mal igualmente se maneja
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }

    };

    return self;
}]);
```

Posterior debes inyectarlo en tu app.js(por omisión en ionic) donde esta el módulo principal

```
var app = angular.module('nombreDeTuApp', ['ionic', 'ciudades'])
//aca va con el nombre con el cual registrate el modulo anterior que en este ejemplo usamos ciudades en minúsculas
```

Luego vamos a consumirlo en el controlador que necesitemos.

```
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, Ciudades) {
//aca puedes ver que estamos usando el nombre ciudades en mayúscula y de esta forma lo vamos a consumir
//por ejemplo supongamos que cargamos los datos de la ciudad 'ABC' pues no se que retorna tu php

$scope.ciudad = {};

$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function () {
    Ciudades.listaCiudades('ABC').then(function(ciudad){
    $scope.ciudad = ciudad;//por tanto en este instante ya se termino la llamada http y estas consumiendo los datos que retorna la promesa($q)
    //recuerda que esto puede tomar un tiempo por lo cual es aconsejable mostrar algún loading hasta que obtengas respuesta
    //y tu vista ya será actualizada
    }, function(error){
    //algo fue mal con la llamada te retorna el error
    });
});


});
```